# Apache axis compatibility with java 11

Tags: java, java-11

We are using apache axis library for web service support. But because of some packages removed from JDK in new versions, we are getting: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/soap/SOAPException`

I am aware of some solutions like adding dependencies as java modules but we have to support Java 6 as well. Is there a solution to make our application to work with Java 6 and the newer ones?

Comment: I believe 6 is the lowest version that JDK11 supports.

Comment: If you are living from the classpath it should be enough to include an old SAAJ jar, e.g. `axis-saaj-1.4.jar` in the case of Axis 1. We have an old application, originally written for Java 1.4, that runs this way on 11.